# Error when running docker image created from nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following problem (OS of the computer is windows with docker desktop installed):

- I have a project in nodejs with express with node version 12.8.0, this project works fine locally, since when running the command: "npm run start" the log shows me the following:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.20 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.* 
[nodemon] watching extensions:js,mjs,json 
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`  
Server up on port 8000
Conectado a la base de datos
```

- In order to run another project with a different version of node(14.15.1) on the same computer, the Dockerfile was created in the aforementioned service with the following content:

```
FROM node:12.8.0-alpine
LABEL Parking Back <carlos.jaramillo@tars.dev>
ENV TZ=America/Bogota
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
WORKDIR /BLOMIBACK
COPY ./package.json ./package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm audit fix 
RUN npm install
RUN npm audit fix --force
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 8004
```

- In order to build the image, run the command: "docker build -t blomiback ."
- To run the image, the command "docker run --name=blomiback1 -p 8004:8004 blomiback" is run, which gives me the following message, so in the end the project does not end up running correctly in docker:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:909
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
```

I hope you can help me because I really don't know what I'm failing or what I need to improve in order to continue working.

The code is in the following "dev" branch repository:
https://gitlab.com/storage20/parking/backend.git

This is the .env file to the project:

```
DB_CONNECT=mongodb://localhots:27017/alquimia_local

PORT=8000

CLIENT_ID_MQTT=blomiJavi DB_MYSQL=blomi_seeders DB_MYSQL_USER=root DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD= DB_MYSQL_HOST=localhost DB_MYSQL_PORT=3306

# DATOS PARA DUVA DUVA_URL=https://duvapi.tars.dev/ DUVA_FROM=noreply@brm.com.co DUVA_FROM_NAME=BRM S.A DUVA_EMAIL=natalia.rodriguez@tars.dev DUVA_PASSWORD=t@1234

#timezone TZ='America/Bogota'

# secret for encryption of jwt signature JWT_SECRET=123456789

# number of rounds for Blowfish algorithm for hashing user password BCRYPT_ROUNDS=12

# terminal TERMINAL_ID=1

# Custom token CUSTOM_TOKEN='CustomSecretToken'

# lifetime of the token (in seconds) JWT_LIFETIME=86400

# algorithm used in token signing JWT_ALGORITHM=HS256

#credentials Microsoft application

OUTLOOK_CLIENT_ID=eed698c9-3372-44af-9257-53b9adbd0e7c

OUTLOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=gud3-F0d1a8nc_pjkBUSUyF9R~j.09KAmU

OUTLOOK_CALLBACK_URL1=http://localhost:8004/api/user/message OUTLOOK_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8080/auth/Outlook URL_BASE_SEND_EMAIL=http://localhost:8081 NODE_MAILER_EMAIL= carlos.jaramillo@tars.dev NODE_MAILER_PASSWORD= BosatzuKon1
```

I hope I can run the project in a docker container that connects to the database without a problem

Answer (score -1):

Well, I did the same actions like you, but I have different error

`TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option`

I tried on `d219d3ceb62da0c7d5e1184b56f9c04d4245310d`

How did you pass config data shown below?

```
passport.use(
  "windowslive",
  new OutlookStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.OUTLOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.OUTLOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.OUTLOOK_CALLBACK_URL,
    },
```

I didn't find it in your repo. Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal documentation states that you have to create a config file, in this case .env

EDIT

I added this line

`require('dotenv').config()`

on top of middleware/passport.js and with your .env it started to work. I had an error about connection to DB, but this is obvious, as I tried one container only.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to a question.  Did you mean to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: I already added the .env file to the project